# Moved silverlight file (xaml) to a different project, and now code behind doesn't recognize the controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I moved a silverlight file (xaml) to a different project, and now code behind for the file doesn't recognize the controls.

xaml.cs file does not see controls in xaml file

I've updated the namespace, but that doesn't help.

I've updated the class names to be the same, still doesn't help.

Intelisence doesn't pick up the controls.

Any ideas?  I tried deleting the cs file as well, but there's no option to "auto re-create cs file"

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VS2010 check the properties of the xaml file.  Its Build Action should be "Page" and its Custom Tool should be "MSBuild:Compile".  Also check that the `x:Class` element in the xaml contains the correct fully qualified name that matches the namespace and class name in the code-behind .xaml.cs file.

Comment: I changed the build action to "Page".  The custom tool was already set to "MSBuild:Compile".  I triple checked the fully qualified name and class name, and they're both correct.  Anymore suggestions?  My co-worker said there may be a "shared" file somewhere else, that needs to be edited, since the .cs file is a "partial class".  Is this true?

Comment: @Fritos: The "shared" file is the .g.i.cs file which should be auto-generated when those settings are correct.  How did you "move" the xaml file?  What type of project have you moved it to?

Comment: I copied the xaml file, then I pasted into another project.  How do I access this .g.i.cs file?  I can't see it in the file system.

Comment: When in degub configuration the .g.i.cs files are generated into the  _project_ /obj/debug folder.  However I'm fairly sure you aren't getting one created which is why you are having these problems.  The question would then be why is this file not being generated for you.  Have you copied it into a __Silverlight__ Class Library project?

Comment: It's actually a SilverLight Application.  And the Project I copied from is also a SilverLight Application.  I see the g.i. files

Comment: @Fritos: So if I've got this straight, both the .xaml and the .xaml.cs file are in the same Silverlight application project.  The .xaml file has a matching .g.i.cs file created in the obj/debug folder?  When you look at the .xaml.cs code does the call to `InitializeComponent` in the constructor have a redline complaining that it doesn't exist?

Comment: Ok, I got it, it was in that .g.i.cs file.  I updated the namespace within it and now everything is fine.  Thanks for your help! +1.

Comment: @Fritos: I'm glad you got it fixed.  I assume when you say "updated the namespace within it" you mean you adjusted the `x:Class` property in the Xaml?

Answer (score 2):

A XAML file generates a partial class, essentially. A code behind file is another partial class with the same name. A class cannot be declared across two different projects, which is what you are doing.

Comment: The code behind file (xaml.cs) is setup as a public partial class.  Are you saying there shouldn't be a xaml.cs file?

Comment: No, I am saying that if there is a .xaml.cs, it has to be in the same project as the XAML.

Comment: There are a number of others things the project files set up. Maybe its just easier to delete both files and recreate the control with both files.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I found the Build Action was changed to Application definition. After changing it to Page, and deleting the obj folder , everything is OK.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the namespace / class name of the XAML file and code-behind? I have often forgotten to change the namespace in the code-behind file when moving a XAMl file to another project.

Comment: Yup, I copy and pasted those names just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem in a WPF project. One thing I noticed is that if you put something like following in  section:

`<x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="RuleBinaryOperatorList"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <sys:String>AND</sys:String>
            <sys:String>OR</sys:String>
 </x:Array>`

It makes the corresponding XAML file not compileable and complaining about InitializeComponent not recognized. The solution is to put such resources into  section inside App.xaml instead.

Hope it helps someone out there!